# Any way to print shape or other information of arguments to objective functions in keras?

Tags: theano, keras

All objective functions in keras take tensor variable arguments y_true and y_pred. I am trying to get the shape (or any relevant tensor attributes) of these arguments with my "custom" mean_squared_error objective:

```
def custom_mse(y_true, y_pred):
    print 'in custom_mse'
    print K.eval(y_true.shape)
    print 'end custom_mse'

    return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```

This gives the following error at model.compile:

```
theano.gof.fg.MissingInputError: ("An input of the graph, used to compute Shape(dense_2_target), was not provided and not given a value.
```

Is there any way to eval the objective arguments' attributes? y_true.shape returns 'Shape.0', but I cannot eval() it like I can any other time I try to eval shape.